# Using external JS-File in AngularJS Project

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">

</script>
<script src="./assets/namesController.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <!-- Method call from external JS files -->
    <br>
    <div ng-controller="ryanContrler">
        My first name : <input type="text" ng-model="ryanFirstname"> 
        <br> My last name : <input type="text" ng-model="austinLastname">        
        <br> My full name : {{fullName()}}
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

namesController.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ryanContrler', ['$scope', function ($scope{
    $scope.ryanFirstname = "Ryan",
    $scope.austinLastname = "Austin",
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.ryanFirstname + " " + $scope.austinLastname;
    }

}]);
```

Hey Guys,

i tried to use an external JS file in my AngularJS Project but no matter what I tried, it didnt seem to recognize the JS file.
The Code Sampels are copied but I understand them, neverthless I cant make them running.

I pasted the JS in the assets Folder. The html file is in the src Folder.

Thank you for your help and ideas!

Error Codes in Chrome: 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqp11.png)
[new Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIJCB.png)

Comment: There is a typo in your controller. 'functio' should be 'function'. Could you check that?

Comment: can you share your directory structure

Comment: Do you have any message from the console?

Comment: The functio typo was only here, not in the actual Code. How can i share it the best way?

Comment: Error Codes have been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller

```
var agentApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

agentApp.controller('ryanContrler',function ($scope){
    $scope.ryanFirstname = "Ryan",
        $scope.austinLastname = "Austin",
        $scope.fullName = function() {
            return $scope.ryanFirstname + " " + $scope.austinLastname;
        }

});
```

your HTML should change as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/namesController.js"></script>
</head>


<body >

<!-- Method call from external JS files -->
<br>
<div ng-controller="ryanContrler">
    My first name : <input type="text" ng-model="ryanFirstname">
    <br> My last name : <input type="text" ng-model="austinLastname">
    <br> My full name : {{fullName()}}
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then Error Code says: "404...namesController.js.js. not found"

Comment: is your assest folder in root folder or inside a another path?

Comment: assets is in the "src" folder

Comment: so just clearly define your path, issue is in the path

Comment: C:\Users\SCHUL256\Angular Projects\sandbox\src\assets\namesController.js. is the clear path

Comment: with the one you told me now i get "file not found" i added the new eror codes... src="../src/assets/namesController.js"         now used

Comment: I have updated my controller code, error says injection issue. you better identify the path of your controller and try it. let's add it and see

Comment: I've added the full code, its works fine for me, You have to declare your angular module properly with your app name as i explained, And id 404 error occurred try to see whether the script in the path it shows in debug window, then you can easily find the path of your external file

Comment: No I didn't, I moved along with Angular 4 and everything works great so far. Still big thanks for your help!